# Google Ads showing ads on search term, not what I intend to show them. How can I resolve?

Tags: google, google-search, keywords, google-ads, ad-targeting

Google Ads showing ads on search term, not what I intend to show them. How can I resolve?

My service/product is providing bulk shoes. My audience are only those, who intend to buy in bulk not single piece.

hence I added keyword "**bulk running shoes**" in phrase match. What I am getting is, this keyword is also showing my ads on search term such as > **Running Shoes** as well.

For me I need the search term/user Query to have **bulk** as mandatory.

Kindly Help to resolve my concern.